# Axon - stuck in 1 event after error occurred

Tags: java, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I recently learned Axon and CQRS & Event Sourcing.

**CMIIW** event store is like an application state, so in Axon we have `org.axonframework.eventhandling.GlobalSequenceTrackingToken` which means we can know the current state of our apps at a certain time from this record right?

```
processor_name   |   segment owner| timestamp                      | token             | token_type
myapps.projection|       0    far |  2021-02-03T02:22:46.6003318Z  | {"globalIndex":32}|  org.axonframework.eventhandling.GlobalSequenceTrackingToken
```

So everything works fine until I forget to do some validation and then my apps stuck in 1 event (`{"globalIndex":32}`) trying to publish this event until successfully.

this happens since my `@Eventhandler` throw an error.

**Explanation:**
I have 2 events, with the same `userName` and the `@EventHandler` cant resolve this and throw error since the `userName must be unique`.

`token:31,payload: {"id":"d6554811-ee5a-46d5-973d-1d61ee71c7fe","fullName":"xasxsax","userName":"xasxsaxsa","email":"xasxsa@g.com","password":"adminadmin"}`

`token:32,payload:{"id":"b41efb71-14ee-4a5f-bdef-93b36e2e6a84","fullName":"xasxsax","userName":"xasxsaxsa","email":"xasxsa@g.com","password":"adminadmin"}`

my question is there any **best practices to handle errors so other events will work well** without waiting to fix this single event? or is there any solution to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Axon 4, and the default TrackingEventProcessor.
The events form a stream, so you have to handle this event before processing the next; throwing an exception from the @EventHandler tells Axon that you are not currently able to process the event.
In this specific case you probably should simply log an error, but not throw, as the second event simply doesn't make sense - it's asking to create something that already exists.

For other types of failing events, it might be interesting to again only log the error and allow the stream to continue, and replay the events afterwards, once you have remedied the cause of the failure. To replay specific events for a single Aggregate, you can do something like this:

```
@Autowired
EventStore eventStore;
    
@Test
public void testReplay() {
    
    String aggregateIdentifier = "1234";
    long startFrom = 0;
    String eventType = "org.sample.model.events.MyEvent";
    Class projectorClass = MyProjector.class;
    
    AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter eventHandlerAdapter = new AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter(projectorClass);
    DomainEventStream eventStream = eventStore.readEvents(aggregateIdentifier, startFrom);
    eventStream.asStream()
        .filter(event -> {
            // add any type of filtering based on the event here
            return event.getType() == eventType;
        })
        .forEach(event1 -> {
            try {
                eventHandlerAdapter.handle(event1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
}
```

You could expose this method in an operational interface to allow your operations team to replay specific events after analysis.

Comment: `as the second event simply doesn't make sense - it's asking to create something that already exists.` yeah, correct. but this happens what should I do? can I remove this event from the event store? I mean really remove from the list not creating a new event. since if I try to replay this event it still errors

Comment: Conceptually, you should never remove an event: it is the Truth, written in stone. You can reset the token of your TrackingEventProcessor. Or, if you are running in an environment with fast deployments, simply fix the 'bug' (i.e. catch the unique-key violation in your @EventHandler and don't rethrow it).

Comment: (for completeness: if you can't deploy a new version of your service: if you're not running with the Axon Server, using your own schema, technically you could delete the row that contains the event (DOMAIN_EVENT_ENTRY). Don't know how your TrackingEventProcessor is going to react when he sees that the event he's supposed to handle doesn't exist; would definitely test this in a different environment first)

Comment: but that event should not exist, I am using Axon Server.

Comment: You've allowed it to enter in the event-source, so it exists. Either the unique constraint is local to your projection, in which case you can only say you can't project the event and take any required compensating measures, or it applies to the aggregate, in which case you should have rejected the event from entering the event-source. Now that it already happened, you have to accept it as truth. You'll run into similar issues in the future when you add new projections; there will probably be old events that don't fit the requirements of the new projection, but it will have to deal with them

Answer (score 3):

In short, a dead letter queue for the failing event would be a nice solution to have. As it stands, Axon Framework does not provide a dead letter queue though. What it does give you, is two levels of error handling you can configure.

First of these is the `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler`. This error handler is invoked for any exception thrown from within your `@EventHandler` annotated function. The `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler` is by default configured to be the `LogginErrorHandler` which, as you might have guessed, simply logs the exception *and proceeds*.

The second level is the so-called `ErrorHandler`. This interface is invoked for transactional exceptions occurring inside your Event Processor. Exceptions which should typically stop your processor working altogether. This error handler defaults to the `PropagatingErrorHandler`, which simply rethrows your exception. Doing so inside (the default) `TrackingEventProcessor` means the event processor enters a retry mode.

From your description, I am assuming you either have a transactional exception or you have configured the `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler` to be a `PropagatingErrorHandler`. If you don't want to stop your processor whenever an exception occurs, you can thus configure it to simply log and proceed with the `LoggingErrorHandler`.

Whether this is smart to do, is a different point altogether though. As Bart in the other post mentioned, these events are in your store as for whatever reason your validation process decided that event happened. As the event store dictates, it is there to stay. Meaning you will have to cope with it. The solution to resolving such a faulty event is to process a compensating action inside your application. A less technical way of describing this necessity can be found [here](https://discuss.axoniq.io/t/how-to-fix-bugs-in-command-handler-with-compromized-events/2982/2?u=steven_van_beelen).

At any length, if the event is faulty, your set up will have to deal with it. Add a try-catch block for example to deal with known possible exceptions. Or make the event handling more resilient altogether for certain issues you would anticipate. Or, go the stretch, and build a dead-letter queue.

Comment: The typo 'coop' as an interesting contamination of 'cope with the event' and 'cooperate with the event store' :)

Comment: Ha, thanks for spotting that Bart. I've noticed I tend to mistype that more often.

Comment: Because projections are based on an aggregate, it would be a nice pattern to store not only the failing event, but all following events on that projector for the aggregate initially failing in such a dead letter queue, with the option of replaying them at a later stage. Same applies to commands and the event-store. Would be a nice feature in Axon.

Comment: As the Framework lead, I can tell you that the consecutive events which would've updated the model should indeed also be part of the dead letter queue. Plans are under way to support this.

Comment: Great! Looking forward to it.